# Compatibility of product topology with the vector space structure

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

I've been struggling with the following rudimentary question and I'd appreciate any help :

Given topological $K$-vector spaces $(E_i)_{i \in I}$, let $E$ be their product and $T$ the product topology on $E$. How exactly do we prove that $T$ is compatible with the vector space structure of $E$, that is how do we prove that the mappings $f:E\times E\rightarrow E,\ (x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $g:K\times E\rightarrow E,\ (\lambda,x)\mapsto \lambda x\ $ \ are both continuous ?
Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we can identify (via the obvious homeomorphism) $E \times E \cong \prod_{i=1}^n E_i \times E_i$. If $\oplus:E \times E \to E$ is addition in $E$ and $\oplus_i: E_i \times E_i \to E_i$ is addition in $E_i$ then under the above identification we have $\oplus = \prod_{i=1}^n \oplus_i$.

Since $\oplus_i$ is continuous for each $i$, it suffices to show that a product of continuous maps is continuous. This is a standard topological result. Indeed, if $f_i: X_i \to Y_i$ are continuous maps of topological spaces then for a basic open set $U_1 \times \dots \times U_k \subseteq \prod_{i=1}^k Y_i$ we have $$(f_1 \times \dots \times f_k)^{-1}(U_1 \times \dots \times U_k) = \prod_{i=1}^k f_i^{-1}(U_i)$$
which is a basic open set in $\prod_{i=1}^k X_i$ and hence $f_1 \times \dots \times f_k$ is continuous.

The same idea will also give the second result, by identifying $\prod_{i=1}^n K \times E_i \cong K^n \times E$ and noting that $\otimes: K \times E \to E$ is then a restriction of the product map $\prod_{i=1}^n \otimes_i$ (up to a composition with the obvious embedding $K \hookrightarrow K^n$ given by $\lambda \mapsto (\lambda, \dots, \lambda)$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here you're considering a product of a finite number of topological spaces, does the same proof hold if we have a family of topological vector spaces which is not finite ?

Comment: @SamiFersi Yep, the key result is that the product of continuous maps is still continuous and you can prove that this is true in the exact same way by considering the preimage of a basic open set in $\prod_{i \in \Lambda} Y_i$.